# execute function in UIViewController from NSObject Class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, nsobject

so I have `NSObject` class that controls something in my code but I want when something is done in `NSObject` class execute method in `UIViewController` class so I used two ways below but none of them doesn't work for me

**1- I used delegate Protocol so in view controller class, I put these**

```
protocol ImagePickerManagerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func showAlert(_ type : Int)
}

class myViewController : UIViewController , ImagePickerManagerDelegate {

   func showAlert(_ type : Int) {
      print(type) 
   }

    let imagePicker = ImagePickerManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       imagePicker.delegate = self
     }
 }
```

and here is the codes in another class

```
class ImagePickerManager: NSObject {
   weak var delegate : ImagePickerManagerDelegate?
   func foo() {
      self.delegate?.showAlert(1)
   }    
 }
```

the foo function will execute and also

```
self.delegate?.showAlert(1)
```

but nothing will happen

**2- I used callBack function But again nothing will happen**

```
class ImagePickerManager: NSObject {
   var ErrorCallback: ((Int) -> ())?

   func ErrorAlert(_ callback: @escaping ((Int) -> ())) {
       ErrorCallback = callback
   }


   func foo() {
      self.ErrorCallback?(1)
   }

}
```

and here is the `UIViewController` Code for CallBackFunction

```
 ImagePickerManager().ErrorAlert(self) { type in
     print(type)
 }
```

I need one of these methods to execute function in my code

Comment: in which class you mean? NSObject Or ViewController?

Comment: self.delegate?.showAlert(1) is in NSObject Class not in my View Controller class

Comment: True, i meant to write `self.imagePicker.delegate?.showAlert(1)`.

Comment: I have to call showAlert when some thing will happen in my NSObject class so the number will produce when that happened so  self.imagePicker.delegate?.showAlert(1) will call when that is done in NSObject class

Comment: Yes, but trying this will give the reason why it works here and not when you actually want it. My guess is a different object of `ImagePickerManager` is being used to call the `showAlert` method(Not the one which is set for delegation).

Comment: I used that but again got the same result

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to trigger something on your view controller class when something happens on your NSObject class you could use a closure.

Your VC class would own an instance of your `NSObject` class as you've done above:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    // Instance of your NSObject class
    let imagePicker = ImagePickerManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // You implement the closure in the VC
        imagePicker.fooHandler = { integer in
            print(integer)
        }

        // Once you've implemented the closure, when the Image Picker's doSomethingWithFoo() is called, it will trigger the closure.
        imagePicker.doSomethingWithFoo(2)
    }
}
```

Your `NSObject` class would define a closure that will be implemented in your VC class and a method that will trigger that closure:

```
class ImagePickerManager: NSObject {

    var fooHandler: ((Int) -> Void)?

    func doSomethingWithFoo(with integer: Int) {
        fooHandler?(integer)
    }
}
```

This is just a simplified example of how you could lay this out but you can set up how and when the closure is called as you see fit.

Comment: this method doSomethingWithFoo() for me require type to because I want to pass the type to the view controller so if I use imagePicker.doSomethingWithFoo(0) for example the  print("Do foo stuff.") will execute immediately but I need that print execute when  func doSomethingWithFoo(type : Int) { has called in NSObject class

Comment: I edited the code to include an Int type that you can pass in the closure and the method

Comment: You just need to move `doSomethingWithFoo()` into your NSObject class. I just put it in the view controller for the example so that it would be called in the viewDidLoad() method but you need to move it wherever you want it to be called in the ImagePickerManager :)

Comment: can I send that class code please ? I used an NSObject class for camera and Gallery with action sheet and all of these are in NSObject Class I check the permission and I just want to pass Int value for camera or gallery when User doesn't allow app to use them